# Wordpress HTTP / HTTPS issue

Tags: php, wordpress, https

Okay, I've moved a site from a dev location to a new domain with an SSL installed on it.

I'm unable to login to the admin area nor am I able to view the homepage of the site.

The database has the correct values for 'home' and 'siteurl':  https://www.example.com

When I echo out the results of site_url(); in my php code - I'm receiving back http://www.example.com (no https).

I've changed the values in the database (via PHPMyAdmin), in the wp-config.php file, etc. but I continue to get the non-secure URL returned.

This creates a never ending loop and no results in the browser.

I've also deactivated any plugins and switched themes to one of the generic themes and the issue still persists.

Any suggestions on what might be the issue and why it seems the https: keeps getting changed to http:???

Comment: You have any caching plugins installed?

Comment: no caching plugins installed.....

Comment: Is it set to `https` in your `.htaccess` file?  This wouldn't affect the output of `site_url()` though, you got me there.

Comment: there is nothing in the .htaccess file other than the normal code generated by a basic WP install - no special rules or code have been added

Comment: So what exactly happens when you try to go to `https://www.example.com/wp-admin`?

Comment: try putting this at the bottom of your `wp-config.php` : `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` and then if you get into admin refresh your permalinks.

Comment: when I go to https://www.example.com/wp-admin/ I get nowhere - just a never ending loop and then the browser just quits trying and gives an error message.

I've also added that to the wp-config.php file but nothigns changes.

Comment: throw `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` into your `wp-config.php` as well. For some reason I thought you said you already did this.

Comment: Well those are all the things I know to remedy this kind of issue, if no one else can chime in I'd say just backup and try a fresh WP install, only takes a few min.

Comment: Once place $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; in the wp-config.php file, I get the login page to load, but when I type my username and password (that I have verified is correct), I get the error message below and it leaves me at the login screen:

ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.

Comment: The only time I've gotten that message is when I was developing locally with a vhost so the live domain pointed to wamp, then when I went live it didn't work until I cleared my browser cache.

Comment: What did you change exactly in the database? The URL is referenced in multiple places. Also is this a standard installation or Multi Site?

Comment: it is a standard installation - I changed it in wp_options - both the 'home' and 'siteurl' values in this table.

I've also download a copy of the database and done a global find/replace.

Same results both times.